# How to sort an array with a limit?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

I want to sort an array using `asort()` and limit the number of elements to return.

Let me give an exeample:

```
$words = array (
["lorem"]=>
int(2)
["sssss"]=>
int(2)
["dolor"]=>
int(4)
["ipsum"]=>
int(2)
["title"]=>
int(1) );
```

with =limit = 2 I would want to have in return:

```
  $words = array (
    ["dolor"]=>
    int(4)    
    ["lorem"]=>
    int(2));
```

In other words, I'll have to sort and return only the first occurances based on `$limit`

any idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
asort($words);
$result = array_slice($words, 0, $limit);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply a limit to asort() but this is a workaround.

```
<?php 
   $words = array("Cat", "Dog", "Donkey");
   $sorted = asort($words);
   $limit = 2;
   $final = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i <= ($limit - 1); $i++) {
       $final[] = $words[$i];
   }
   var_dump($final);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second one makes no sense. He wants the two highest sorted-order elements, not the first two in sorted-order.

Comment: Yes thank you, removed the unneeded solution. array_slice is a much better solution either way. Cheers.

Comment: Your solution is completely valid and easy to understand.

Comment: Note `asort` returns a boolean, and `asort` is designed for associative array.